# Best way to alter array of objects inside an object (using a string path)

Tags: javascript

This may be simpler than I think but is there an easy way to alter the array inside this object using a string:

```
var temp = {
    members: [
    {file_name: 'abc', file_link: 'www'}
  ]
}
```

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
const name = "members[0].file_name" // STRING
temp = {...temp, [name]: 'changed'}
```

Output it's giving me:

[image]

Yes I can split that string to give me the keys and index then change the object the normal way but I was just wondering if there is an easier way about it.

Comment: you will have to go with lodash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at lodash's set function that takes in a string path, and returns the nested object.

lodash does the parsing for you, so you don't have to

https://dustinpfister.github.io/2018/12/04/lodash_set/

Comment: Thank you! I tried using the eval function without splitting the key but I could get it to work properly. Lodash works fine!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function which will return the object you want in accordance with a path

```js
const temp = {
  members: [{
    file_name: 'abc',
    file_link: 'www'
  }]
}

const path = "members[0].file_name";

// Obtain last key (file_name)
const lastKey = path.split(".").at(-1);
// Obtain the path to the last key (members[0])
const previousPath = path.substr(0, path.length - (lastKey.length + 1));
// Get the object with the path (temp.members[0])
const e = eval(`temp.${previousPath}`)
// Modify object
e[lastKey] = "xyz";

console.log(temp)
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. Yes I did come across a similar answer in another thread but I was wondering if I can do that without splitting the string. I went with the lodash approach but this is a good solution too!

Comment: @SFaz Since there isn't a copy-by-reference operator in js, you will need to split last key in order to modify the actual object. Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this the following way

```js
var temp = {
    members: [
    {file_name: 'abc', file_link: 'www'}
  ]
}

const name = "file_name" // STRING
temp.members[0][name] = "changed";

console.log(temp);
```

Or like this:

```js
var temp = {
    members: [
    {file_name: 'abc', file_link: 'www'}
  ]
}

const name = "file_name";
const arr = "members";
temp[arr][0][name] = "changed";

console.log(temp);
```